# Outlook Add-In to Save Emails After Sending

Tags: api, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm looking to create an Add-In for Outlook that allows users to save emails, which are saved against a company in our system. Currently this works by the user opening an email and clicking a button I've created which opens the taskpane containing a form (which asks the user to select a company against which the email will be saved, and optionally provide an email description), whereupon pressing 'save' the email's ID and other relevant information are sent to an API which fetches the email from the rest API and saves the file in our system.

This technically works, though ideally I would like some functionality along the lines of:

- User sends an email
- my add-in to ask the user if they want to save the email immediately after they sending
- If 'yes' is clicked, for the email saving form to appear in either the taskpane or a separate window so it can be saved

This is simply so they don't have to navigate through to their sent messages after sending and save them manually.

Currently I have tried using the ItemSend event for this, however it seems this is more for appending things to the email *before* it sends rather than after, and I don't seem to be able to use this event to get the email item or its ID. I had thought about potentially using the event to send the email to a custom mailbox and have it save as a result of this using a flow of some kind, however I think this would be rather difficult to implement due to needing user input to save the email in our system.

Comment: Have you considered using displayDialogAsync from ItemSend event?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows.  You can ask for user input in the dialog.  I'd like to know more about not being able to get the item id.  Which API do you use in taskpane and does the same approach not work with ItemSend?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I had originally intended to do that, but in the taskpane i was using Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId and sending it to my API endpoint which would then retrieve the mail file, however when I do this in the dialog box an error is thrown as apparently 'item' is undefined. I would guess this is because Outlook is not currently viewing an email from a mailbox, rather it's still in the composing stage, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId is only available for Message Read. To get the itemId in Message Compose, use getItemIdAsync as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview#getItemIdAsync_options__callback_ Could you elaborate more on what data is being saved when the email is saved? Are you saving the body content/recipients/etc?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT from what I can tell, getItemIdAsync comes from Office.context.mailbox, correct? Because it seems that context.mailbox is undefined when opening a form upon ItemSend, so unless that function can be accessed elsewhere, or my add-in's permissions are incorrect somehow, I don't seem to be able to use it :/

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT and the data I'm saving is the entire email as a .eml file. Once I have the ID it is sent to my API, which in turn uses a graph service client to request the content of the email, which is then saved as a .eml file.

Comment: getItemIdAsync is defined on the item as Office.context.mailbox.item.getItemIdAsync. Also, the messageParent function and Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported are the only two Office JS APIs that can be called in the dialog box. The dialog can send the parent a message, and when the Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived event is received, the parent can access the itemId in the callback. This behavior is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#send-information-from-the-dialog-box-to-the-host-page

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT that seems really close to what I want, however I'm not sure I can get the itemId still. When i call getItemIdAsync at the beginning of the file, it fails with the message of "The id can't be retrieved until the item is saved."

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT however when I attempt to getItemIdAsync in my onSend handler function after calling `dialog.close()` and `res.completed({ allowEvent: true })`, the callback function does not seem to fire at all, and logging mailbox.item seems to no longer show getItemIdAsync as a property of the item at all.

Comment: I think a snippet of your code will be helpful here. It appears you are calling `getItemIdAsync` after completing the onSend handler, which results in undefined behavior. In other words, you should call `getItemIdAsync` after `dialog.close()`, and then in the callback for `getItemIdAsync`, do everything you need, and then call `res.completed({ allowEvent : true })`

Comment: It is also worth nothing that after an item is sent, that the EWSId will change. (since EWSId is folder based). You may have a race condition to fetch the item from the server, and between the time it is sent. (even if the above fixes your issue)